# Set cursor inside ComboBox to the end of the text

Tags: c++, user-interface, winapi, mfc

I am trying to set the cursor to the end of the ComboBox edit text. I try using `CB_SETEDITSEL` to set it, but it doesn't work. Instead of putting the cursor at the end of the text, it selects the whole text:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, textID, CB_SETEDITSEL, textLength, textLength);
```

Weirdly enough, `EM_SETSEL` works for an edit control:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, textID, EM_SETSEL, textLength, textLength);
```

Both `EM_SETSEL` and `CB_SETEDITSEL` have basically the same documentation.

Comment: _"Both EM_SETSEL and CB_SETEDITSEL have basically the same documentation"_: not quite. Read closely what wParam and lParam do for [CB_SETEDITSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/cb-seteditsel) and [EM_SETSEL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-setsel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks jabberwocky for pointing out that the documentation for the two is different with their use of LPARAM.

CB_SETEDITSEL doesn't use WPARAM

EM_SETSEL uses both LPARAM and WPARAM

To do what I wanted for the combo box:

```
SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, textID, CB_SETEDITSEL, 0, MAKELPARAM(textLength,textLength));
```